# Cannot access admin page after EPiServer CMS 6 R2 to 7.5 upgrade

Tags: episerver-7

I have upgraded a site from EPiServer CMS 6 R2 to 7.5 via Deployment Center. After running the "Upgrade/disable Add-ons After Product Upgrade" I cannot access the back-end/admin page.

Error:

```
Exception details: 
ActivationException: Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type EPiDashboardController, key "" 

Stack trace:
[ActivationException: Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type EPiDashboardController, key ""]
at EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
at EPiServer.Shell.Web.Mvc.ModuleControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at EPiServer.Shell.Web.Mvc.ModuleMvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at EPiServer.Shell.Web.Mvc.ModuleMvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

[Inner exception StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  207
Internal exception while creating Instance '0512faec-bb98-447c-a311-5bde00402363' of PluginType EPiServer.Shell.ViewComposition.IViewManager.  Check the inner exception for more details.]
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance)
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get[T](String propertyName, BuildSession session)
at lambda_method(Closure , IArguments )
at StructureMap.Construction.BuilderCompiler.FuncCompiler`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IArguments args)
at StructureMap.Construction.InstanceBuilder.BuildInstance(IArguments args)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.SmartInstance`1.build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance)
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Get[T](String propertyName, BuildSession session)
at lambda_method(Closure , IArguments )
at StructureMap.Construction.BuilderCompiler.FuncCompiler`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IArguments args)
at StructureMap.Construction.InstanceBuilder.BuildInstance(IArguments args)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session, IInstanceBuilder builder)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.createRawObject(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.Instance.Build(Type pluginType, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.Pipeline.ObjectBuilder.Resolve(Type pluginType, Instance instance, BuildSession session)
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance)
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType)
at EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by giving folder permissions to IIS_IUSRS